# set a timestamp in the first blank cell in a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do 2 things in a spreadsheet each time a cell in col8 is selected. 1st increase the value of the cell in col7 and set a timestamp in the first blank cell in the row. I'm stuck on the timestamp. Increasing the value works and I can set the timestamp to a specific cell as show in the code or in the last col of the sheet, but I can't find a solution to set it in the first blank cell of the row.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  if (as.getName() == 'Sheet1' && col == 8){ 
        const range = as.getRange(row,7);
        range.setValue(range.getValue()+1);
        e.range.setValue('Present');
  }
  onEdit(e);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var attendanceSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(attendanceSheet.getName() == 'Sheet1' && col == 8) {
    
    if (attendanceSheet.getRange(row, 12).getValue() === '')
    attendanceSheet.getRange(row, 12).setValue(new Date());    
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {

  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  if (as.getName() == 'Sheet1' && col == 8) {
    const range = as.getRange(row, 7);
    range.setValue(range.getValue() + 1);
    e.range.setValue('Present');

    const array = as.getRange(row, 1, 1, as.getLastColumn()+1).getValues()[0];
    const empty_col = array.indexOf('') + 1;
    as.getRange(row, empty_col).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

But frankly, I doubt that it's a good idea.

Comment: thanks it worked just fine. I just moved the empty_col array  after col 9 indexOf('', 9) to escape any data change in col 1-8

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the empty cell in that specific row:

```
  const vals = ws.getRange(iRow, 1, 1, iColMax).getValues();
  for(var iCol=0; iCol<iColMax; iCol++) {
    if( vals[0][iCol] == "" ) {
      //Logger.log(`Cell in Row ${iRow} Col ${iCol+1} is empty`);
      ws.getRange(iRow,iCol+1).setValue(new Date());
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Probably you need to break the loop after the `setValue()`. Otherwise it will fill all empty cells of the row.

Comment: 100% right @YuriKhristich

Answer (score 1):

IMHO is a very bad idea to call an `onEdit` function (a simple installable trigger) from an `onSelectionChange` function (another simple installable trigger) as there might be cases when an edit will occur immediately after a selection change occurs.

If you are looking to avoid repeating the timestamping code on two simple triggers, then "promote" the timestamping code into a function and call it from both triggers.

```
function onSelectionChange(){
  // Some code here
  timestamping();
}

function onEdit(){
  // Some code here
  timestamping();
}

function timestamping() {
  // timestamping code here
}
```

Regarding setting the timestamp in first blank cell in a row, using `indexOf` you might get the column, you might use something like this:

```
var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
/** Get the edited row values */
var rowValues = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
/** Get the column of first empty cell */
var column = rowValues.indexOf('') + 1;
/** First evaluate if there was found and empty cell, if so, add the timestamp, otherwsie do nothing */
if(column > 0) attendanceSheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(new Date());
```